# 10fold Cross Validation R

Tags: r, classification, cross-validation

I am a bit newbe here! 
I have a question for you. 
I was programming in R. It was a normal classification concept with not much data so i had to do 10 fold validation to be sure for my predictions.
For example i made a Naive Bayes model:

```
naiveb <- naiveBayes(X ~ Y, data=training_set)
```

made my predictions and everything went fine. After that i made 10 fold cross validation like this :

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method= "repeatedcv", repeats = 10)
inTrain <- createDataPartition(normTrain$Feature, p = .75, list = FALSE)
Cvtraining <- train[inTrain,]
Cvtesting <- train[-inTrain,]
NBFit <- train(Feature ~ Υ, data = Cvtraining, method="nb",
      tuneLength = 15, trControl = ctrl, preProc = c("center", "scale"))
```

So my question is, in `method ="nb"` we choose `"nb"` cause we want to see how naive bayes generalize in new data.But why we choose `"nb"` and not `"naive_bayes"`
based on documentation they are both for classification and they have both the same tunign parameters. Also shouln't be our model in the 10 fold validation?? 
I mean how `naiveb` and `nb` are compared ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation:

method `nb` uses naive bayes from the `klaR` package.

method `naive_bayes` uses naive bayes from the `naivebayes` package.

They do have the same tuning parameters, but you should read the documentation of the respective packages which you want to use.

In the `train` function you specify which model you want to use, in `trainControl` you specify which overhead control mechanisms you want to use.

With caret you can compare models with each other. You can find more info [here](http://topepo.github.io/caret/model-training-and-tuning.html#between-models).